# PHP treats an array as an object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm not a PHP developer so I may be doing something wrong. I'm trying to decode JSON string and insert some values to mysql database. I'm getting a valid array of json objects (tested with jsonlint), so I'm adding them one by one to database. But php throws :

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` error.

This is the code :

```
$array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

for($i = 0, $l = sizeof($array); $i < $l; $i++){
    $obj = $array[$i];

    echo "ARRAY1: ".$array;
    echo "L: ".$l;
    echo "ARRAY2: ".gettype($array);

    $q = 'INSERT INTO dependencies SET projectID = "1", `from` = "'.$obj->{'From'}.'", to = "'.$obj->{'To'}.'", type = "'.$obj->{'Type'}.'", cls = "'.$obj->{'Cls'}.'", lag = "'.$obj{'Lag'}.'"';
```

Error is thrown from line `$q = 'INSERT INTO...` and the printed variables show that indeed my $array is an Array :

`ARRAY1: ArrayL: 2ARRAY2: array` . What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: if you want to print content of an array, use `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` rather than echo

Comment: Take care of that [***SQL INJECTION***](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

Comment: I may have found the answer by mistake , someone suggests to use second parameter for json_decode. Is PHP this dumb to return an array which is not an array ?

Comment: Is PHP doing what? Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php to understand what a function is supposed to do, before using that function and guessing what it does. The manual is the single most useful PHP resource available online. As is the case with most programming languages and tools.

Comment: The array is an array. The JSON objects inside the array are objects though, and you're screwing up the usage of that object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns an object, unless you specify you want an array with the second optional argument:

```
json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
```

**Some other useful advice:**

Use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for debugging purposes. It will help you understand the structure of any objects/arrays in your code.

You should not be accepting data through post and the using it in an SQL query without any sanitation, anyways. I highly recommend you fix that asap.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `->` in the last assignment:

```
$obj{'Lag'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is as Paul pointed out and I'd advise this one.  But if you ever need to cast an array as an object use:

```
$newObject = (object) $oldArray;
```